# Using QFileSystemModel in a QCompleter

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qfilesystemmodel

How does one use `QFileSystemModel` in the context of a `QCompleter`? It looks like a better choice than `QDirModel` as it is non UI-blocking. The following snippet doesn't seem to do anything.

```
QLineEdit* l = new QLineEdit ;
QCompleter* c = new QCompleter ;
QFileSystemModel* m = new QFileSystemModel ;
m->setRootPath( "c:\\" ) ;
c->setModel( m ) ;
l->setCompleter( c ) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it just hasn't been implemented yet.

http://qt.nokia.com/developer/task-tracker/index_html?method=entry&id=221860

Comment: Hi, your link is dead. I tried to google the id in your link but found nothing. Do you have any idea where it is now ?